# How to write a concise regular expression for all strings containing "a"s, "b"s, and "c"s but no more than 2 "b"s and 3 "c"s

Tags: regex, formal-languages, language-theory

I very recently began learning regular expressions and was trying to write one for the question above. It would not be difficult if the limits were only placed on one letter (e.g. no more than 2 "b"s).

Then the answer would be: a* c*(b|ε)a* c*(b|ε)a* c*

But with 2 "b"s and 3 "c"s, the total number of possible orderings between the "a"s is 24 (5 choose 3), so writing a regular expression to contain all those possibilities would be very hefty (since we can choose any number of bs and cs as long as the number is less than 2 and 3 respectively) (ex. bcbcc, cbbcc, bcbc, bcc, b, c,...).

So is it possible to write a concise regular expression for the question or can at least the writing out of the possibilities by simplified?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think in this case you want to negate what you're looking for because finding more than two b's or c's is easy.  You can do this`(?!.*b.*b.*|.*c.*c.*c.*)` and say, no more that 2 b's and 3 c's

Comment: That can contain 'd' or anything else, though

Comment: you can replace `.` with whatever character class you like, it was just a more succinct answer like this

Comment: Thank you very much! But is it possible to do this without negation - I'm doing this problem from a book and we haven't learned the '.' or negation in regex. Also @CarlosBribiescas sorry for the downvote - hit it by accident and it won't let me upvote it now because of lack of points.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I'm not familiar with the '.' in regex but given that the language is of "a"s, "b"s, and "c"s, would it be correct to replace the .* with a*?

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think no.  Because like you say, you have to enumerate the possibilities and I dont know of a way to do that with regex other than enumerating them.  To your question about `.`, i think in this case you can replace it with `a*`

Comment: I see. So otherwise I would need to enumerate all the possibilities. Ok. Thank you very much!

Comment: No, I don't think you can replace with `a*` as then the first alternative would be just `a`'s and `b`'s. (and so would fail to match` abcbabc`) You can probably replace the first three with `[ac]*` and the last three with `[ab]*`? But as the answer stands, that regexp doesn't meet the spec.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
^(?=(?:[ac]*b){1,2}[ac]*$)(?=(?:[ab]*c){1,3}[ab]*$)
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               : begining of string
  (?=           : look ahead
    (?:         : non capture group
      [ac]*     : letters a or c 0 or more times
      b         : letter b
    ){1,2}      : the group must be present once or twice
    [ac]*       : letters a or c 0 or more times
    $           : end of string
  )
  (?=           : look ahead
    (?:         : non capture group
      [ab]*     : letters a or b 0 or more times
      c         : letter c
    ){1,3}      : the group must be present once or three times
    [ab]*       : letters a or b 0 or more times
    $           : end of string
  )
```